# How to reload my code when WooCommerce updates the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have a small amount of code I need to implement on my job's [website](https://secularhumanism.org/go-joan/):

```
window.onload = (function(){
    if ( document.querySelector('input#wc_checkout_add_ons_2.input-text') ){


        console.log("Mailing Code Check Initialized...");

        var submitButton = document.getElementById('place_order')
        var mailingCodeBox = document.querySelector('input#wc_checkout_add_ons_2.input-text');

        submitButton.disabled = true;
        mailingCodeBox.style.border = '2px solid #d83d3d';

        function authenticateInput(){
            if (mailingCodeBox.value == ''){
                mailingCodeBox.style.border = '2px solid #d83d3d';
                submitButton.disabled = true;
            } else {
                mailingCodeBox.style.border = '2px solid #52db6b';
                submitButton.disabled = false;
            }
        }


        mailingCodeBox.addEventListener('input', authenticateInput, false);

        submitButton.addEventListener('click', authenticateInput, false);

    }
}());
```

Essentially, it is authenticating that *something* has been written to the input box.

WooCommerce updates the page and it's checkout modules, however, breaking my code (the submit button is no longer able to be disabled by my script). Is there a work-around for this? Can I reload my script after WooCommerce modules update? I have tried `$( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals')` and `$( document.body ).on( 'updated_wc_div')` neither have helped. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once Woo updates the DOM, your bindings are abandoned / lost.  This is not difficult to overcome - you simply need to learn about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).  Since jQuery is ubiquitous in WordPress / WooCommerce, may I recommend using jQuery, and learning to use event delegation via [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @cale_b thank you for your response! is there a way to tell what event is being triggered by WooCommerce? As I said, I already tested the above functions with jQuery to no avail.

Comment: Show how you tested with jQuery.  "I already tested" doesn't allow us to review what you're doing, how you're binding, etc.

Comment: @cale_b this may be higher level than I am at right now, essentially what I did was wrap my code in a `$( document.body ).on( 'updated_wc_div')`, I suppose I'm somewhat confused as to how these functions work, figuring they were event listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your code when woocormerce finishes updating the dom like:

```
$(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function(){
    if ( document.querySelector('input#wc_checkout_add_ons_2.input-text') ){


        console.log("Mailing Code Check Initialized...");

        var submitButton = document.getElementById('place_order')
        var mailingCodeBox = document.querySelector('input#wc_checkout_add_ons_2.input-text');

        submitButton.disabled = true;
        mailingCodeBox.style.border = '2px solid #d83d3d';

        function authenticateInput(){
            if (mailingCodeBox.value == ''){
                mailingCodeBox.style.border = '2px solid #d83d3d';
                submitButton.disabled = true;
            } else {
                mailingCodeBox.style.border = '2px solid #52db6b';
                submitButton.disabled = false;
            }
        }


        mailingCodeBox.addEventListener('input', authenticateInput, false);

        submitButton.addEventListener('click', authenticateInput, false);

    }
});
```

You can find more of these events in their js files because they're not documented. For Checkout events see https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js

Comment: alternatively, can I write `jQuery(document.body).on('updated_checkout')`? Since I'll need to start my code off with some default states when the page loads, then reload those states in a function when the DOM updates. Or should I use `$(window).on('load', function{})` wrapped around what you wrote?